# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined" in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and js in general and i'm following a crash course on react on got stuck on this error at some point of the course
I get this error on chrome when i open http://localhost:3000/ even when in the console it says "compiled successfully".
i looked arround other topics on the site but none answerd my question

Here is the 2 files concerned

AddTodo.js

```
export class AddTodo extends Component {  
    onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.addTodo(this.state.title);
      this.setState({ title: '' });
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <form  style = {{display:'flex'}} onSubmit={this.onSubmit()} >
          <input type="text" name='title' style = {{flex:'10' , padding:'5px'}} placeHolder="Ajouter une Tâche..." value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/> 
          <input type = "submit" value="Ajouter" className="btn" style = {{flex:'1'}} />
      </form>
    )}
```

App.js

```
addTodo = (title) => {const newTodo = {id : 5,title,completed : false,}
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <AddTodo addTodo ={this.addTodo}/>
      <Todos todos={this.state.todos} markComplete={this.markComplete} delTodo={this.delTodo} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing the function *immediately*:

```
onSubmit={this.onSubmit()}
```

Which means two things:

1. No event argument is being passed to it, hence the error.
2. The *result* of the function is being used as the submit handler, which is also `undefined`.

Don't execute the function, just pass the function itself as a reference to be executed by the system later, when the form is submitted:

```
onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `onSubmit={this.onSubmit()}` with `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`, otherwise you can't access the `e` params.

```
<form  style = {{display:'flex'}} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
   <input type="text" name='title' style = {{flex:'10' , padding:'5px'}} placeHolder="Ajouter une Tâche..." value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/> 
   <input type = "submit" value="Ajouter" className="btn" style = {{flex:'1'}} />        
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have issues while assigning the function on **onSubmit**:

```
 <form  style = {{display:'flex'}} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
```

As per your code `onSubmit={this.onSubmit()}`, it doesn't assigns but executes the code with render itself, not on submit.